# How to refresh token's expire time in redis for SSO?

Tags: java, web, redis

When the client(browser) visits any resource,the token's expiration time should be updated(delay),how to implements this requirement?
Use a interceptor or a filter,and re-set the token into redis server?

Comment: Which redis driver you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do it.

***1. Tweaking the configuration of Redis server. [self descriptive redis.conf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/redis.conf)***

---

`maxmemory-policy <POLICY>` replace this `<POLICY>` by,

```
# volatile-lru -> Evict using approximated LRU among the keys with an expire set.
# allkeys-lru -> Evict any key using approximated LRU.
# volatile-lfu -> Evict using approximated LFU among the keys with an expire set.
# allkeys-lfu -> Evict any key using approximated LFU.
```

***2. Updating the ttl value while accessing the data.[Jedis expire](http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/jedis-2.1.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#expire(java.lang.String,%20int))***

---

If you are using jedis(redis java driver.) then you can set the TTL of that key by, `jedis.expire(key, time_after_expire_in_second)`;

```
   expire(String key, int seconds) 
      Set a timeout on the specified key.

   expireAt(String key, long unixTime) 
      EXPIREAT works exctly like EXPIRE but instead to get the number of seconds representing the Time To Live of the key as a second argument (that is a relative way of specifing the TTL), it takes an absolute one in the form of a UNIX timestamp (Number of seconds elapsed since 1 Gen 1970).
```

---

Comment: but when to refresh the token expiration time in redis server?

Comment: If you want to extend its expire time on each access, extends expire time after the access.